# Existence of complementary subspaces for $dim(V) = 2k$

Tags: vector-spaces

I would like to show that, for any vector space $V$ with $dim(V) = 2k$ (in other words, with an even dimension)  there exist three pair-wise complementary subspaces $S1,S2,S3$ such that:

$$V= S1 \oplus S2=S2\oplus S3=S3\oplus S1 $$

Is there a way of proving this with the help of linear self transformations, and if so, where would I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k=1$ just take three vectors $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ such that every pair of them is a basis of $V$ (e.g. $v_3=v_1+v_2$ once a basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is chosen).

Now work by induction in the case $k+1$.

Choose any splitting $V_{k+1}=V_k\oplus V_1$ where $V_1$ has dimension $2$.

Given an inductive choice of $S_1$, $S_2$ and $S_3$ for the $2k$-dimensional space $V_k$, let $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ be three vectors in $V_1$ as in the $k=1$ case.

Then the spaces $S_i^\prime=\langle S_i,v_i\rangle$, $i=1,2,3$, solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Chose a basis $v_1,\dotsc,v_{2k}$ of $V$ and define
$$\begin{align*}S1:=&span(v_1,v_2,\dotsc,v_k),\\ S2:=&span(v_{k+1},v_{k+2},\dotsc,v_{k+k})\\ S3:=&span(v_1+v_{k+1},v_2+v_{k+2},\dotsc,v_k+v_{k+k})\end{align*}$$